# Trying to transcribe using ascii values using ord and chr

Tags: python, chr, ord

Trying to make an encrypter that shifts ascii values of each character in a message by the value of a corresponding character in a password - Output always results in either a single character or a string index out of range error:

```
msg = input()
pw = input()
pwN = 0
msgN = 0

for i in msg:
    newmsg =""
    nchar = chr(ord(msg[msgN]) + ord(pw[pwN]))
    pwN += 1
    msgN += 1
    if pwN > len(pw):
        pwN = 0
    newmsg += nchar

print (newmsg)
```

Running it in this form results in a single character rather than a message length string in some cases, and in others gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file", line 8, in <module>
    nchar = str(chr(ord(msg[msgN]) + ord(pw[pwN])))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: You could improve your question by giving examples of msg and pw values along with the wished output values of newmsg.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're setting `newmsg` to the empty string in each loop. Moving `newmsg = ""` before the `for` loop should fix the issue of single characters, although figuring out the out of range error is difficult because of your manual increasing of several indices while also iterating over `msg`.

I would suggest taking a look at the iteration features Python offers. You are technically iterating over `msg`, but never actually use `i`, instead relying solely on indices. A more pythonic way to solve this might be as follows:

```
from itertools import cycle

msg = input()
pw = input()

newmsg = ""
for mchar, pwchar in zip(msg, cycle(pw)): # cycle loops the password so that abc becomes abcabcabc...
    newmsg += chr(ord(mchar) + ord(pwchar))
print(newmsg)
```

if you want to stick to the loop. I would even use a generator expression to make it

```
from itertools import cycle

msg = input()
pw = input()

newmsg = "".join(chr(ord(mchar) + ord(pwchar)) for mchar, pwchar in zip(msg, cycle(pw)))
print(newmsg)
```